# How to flatten a numpy matrix for printing

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to flatten a numpy matrix for better printing:

I've tried:

```
import numpy as np 
latt_const = 4.05
lattice = np.matrix([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
])
lattice_cmd = "custom {} a1 {} {} {} a2 {} {} {} a3 {} {} {}".format(
    latt_const, *lattice.flatten()
)
```

But this throws an exception:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I could use lattice.flatten().tolist()[0] but this seems ugly to me, I suspect there is probably a better solution

Comment: you amost *certainly* shouldn't be using `np.matrix`... just use `np.array`.

Comment: So, the *only point* of a `np.matrix` is that it maintains it's 2D-nature. There probably *isn't* a better solution involving `np.matrix`, but again, you shouldn't be using `np.matrix` anyway, unless you are trying to maintain legacy code.. Note, that is [explicitely recommended in the numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use)

Comment: Try `latice.A1`, that makes a 1d array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.array` instead of `np.matrix` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use .format, this function expects two arguments {} {}, which, in your case are latt_const and lattice.flatten(). The problem in your code is that you don't need to insert ten {}, you just need two of them.

This should work:

```
import numpy as np 
latt_const = 4.05
lattice = np.matrix([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
])
print("custom {} My_Matrix {} ".format(latt_const, lattice.flatten(0)))
```

or in case you need them separated, try out:

```
import numpy as np
latt_const = 4.05
lattice = np.matrix([
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1],
])
a1 = lattice[0,:]  # first row
a2 = lattice[1,:]  # second row
a3 = lattice[2,:]  # third row
print("custom {} a1 {} a2 {} a3 {} ".format(latt_const, a1, a2, a3))
```

Comment: In my use case I need separate the numbers via 'a1', 'a2', tags as in the format of the question. Printing all the elements of the matrix at once would not properly pass the commands to the underlying program.